# Trying to implement SSO with Azure active directory and API authentication using Azure/MSAL

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I am trying to implement SSO with Azure Active Directory and  API authentication using Azure AD/MSAL but I am  facing the issues described below.

1. After authentication, `idToken` is generated and this is saved in the local storage and attached automatically to API calls which is treated as unauthorized with error "Invalid token" "Audience is invalid", because ID token cannot be used for API authentication.
2. After authentication I am calling `acquireTokenSilent` method to get an access token. I am able to get the token and set it but at the time of API call, the token attached to th Authorization header is the ID token, not the access token. **How do you configure `Msalinterceptor` to attach the access token to the Authorization header instead of the ID token?**
3. To test the access token, I used Postman and hit the API. Again, authorization failed (Unauthorized 401) with error message saying "Invalid token", "Signature is invalid." In jwt.io also it shows invalid signature. **What is wrong with the signature?**

This is the snapshot of my code:

```
this.subscriptionLoginSuccess = this.broadcastService.subscribe("msal:loginSuccess", (payload) => {

      const accessTokenRequest = ["user.read", "api://[scope]"];

        this.msalAuthService.acquireTokenSilent(accessTokenRequest);
}
```

Thanks!

Edit:Configuration in app.module.ts

```
MsalModule.forRoot({
      clientID: 'clientID',
      authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tanentId',
      validateAuthority: true,
      redirectUri: 'https://localhost:5001/',
      cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
      storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE,
      postLogoutRedirectUri: 'https://localhost:5001/auth/login',
      navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true,
      popUp: false,
      consentScopes: ["api://WebApiClientId/api-access"],
      unprotectedResources: ['https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/'],
      protectedResourceMap: protectedResourceMap,      
      piiLoggingEnabled: true,
    }),

 providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,     
      useClass: MsalInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
```

Comment: You should call acquireTokenSilent with only one API's scopes. So you will need two calls if you want to call your API and MS Graph API.

Comment: Yes i am using one scope only. I don't want to use ms graph api. Just want to access own application's APIs. Also in jwt.io i see nonce in token's header, is it causing invalid signature? If yes, then how to get rid of it?

Comment: In your sample code you have used two scopes from different APIs.

Comment: Ok, Got it, Thanks!, But what about the first problem regarding id token getting attached to the API calls instead of access token? Is there any way to instruct msalinterceptor?

Comment: Hmm, not sure about that one. How have you configured it?

Comment: Just added these lines in app.module.ts :
  providers: [ {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: MsalInterceptor,
        multi: true
    }
   ],

Comment: @user2413365 can you please update your question with that configuration from app.module.ts, and also a snippet showing how your API is validating the token it receives?

Comment: I removed "user.read" from all the places and got JWT without nonce and now no signature is invalid error anymore. Thanks @junnas! But new error is coming now saying "Audience is invalid".  @Philippe Signoret I am just using [Authorize] attribute in my APIs.

Comment: Sorted Audience invalid error but now "www-authenticate →Bearer" with 401 unauthorized. What does that mean?